# C++11 atomic library std::compare_and_exchange semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, atomic

If `sequenceNumber` is `atomic<int>` (seq_no is just an int),

Why does

```
sequenceNumber.compare_exchange_strong(sequenceNumber, seq_no );
```

not compile ?

I had a comparison operation with the atomic variable sequenceNumber before the `compare_exchange_strong` operation and wanted to check if the value of sequenceNumber had been changed by the other thread by the time I actually came to update it in my thread.

Something like this:

```
if ( seq_no > sequenceNumber )
      sequenceNumber.compare_exchange_strong(sequenceNumber, seq_no);
```

I fixed it by:

```
int current_sequence_number = sequenceNumber.load();
if ( seq_no > current_sequence_number )
    sequenceNumber.compare_exchange_strong(current_sequence_number, seq_no );
```

But I am wondering why the compiler does not allow me to use an `atomic<int>` in place of the first argument, i.e. the "expected" parameter in the function call -

```
bool compare_exchange_strong( T& expected, T desired,
                              std::memory_order order = 
                                  std::memory_order_seq_cst );
```

What was the motivation behind disallowing an atomic variable in place of the expected argument especially when `seq_no > sequenceNumber` seems to be allowed ?

By the way, is using `seq_no > sequenceNumber` also wrong ? (even though it compiles) Should I go for `seq_no > sequenceNumber.load()` in that case as well ?

Comment: What is `sequenceNumber`? In what way, if at all, is it related to `sequence_number`?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Those were typos. I fixed them. I am really, really sorry for them. Will you please take a look at the question again ?

Comment: `atcmic<T>` provides a conversion `operator T()` which does the same thing as `load()`. This is why you can use an instance of `atomic<T>` wherever a value of `T` is required. `seq_no > sequence_number` is equivalent to `seq_no > sequence_number.load()`

Comment: Ok, but why does the `operator T()` not work for `compare_exchange_strong` ?

Comment: `operator T()` gives you an rvalue of type `T`. `compare_exchange_strong` expects an lvalue - a non-const reference. `atomic<T>` cannot be converted to `T&`. If it allowed a direct access to underlying storage, you could modify it bypassing its "atomic-ness". For an atomic, every load and store matters, as they affect synchronization with other threads.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot. Why don't you add an answer ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`atomic<T>::compare_exchange_strong` takes `T&` as its first parameter. `atomic<T>` is not convertible to `T&` (even though it is convertible to an rvalue of type `T`; such a conversion just calls `load()`).

If `atomic<T>` were convertible to `T&`, it would effectively give unrestricted access to underlying raw storage, and allow users to modify it at will, bypassing any synchronization mechanisms. Which would thoroughly defeat the point of having an `atomic` in the first place.